# Unable to get OAuth "Request Token" while working with the Tumblr API using Python

Tags: python, api, oauth, tumblr

I've been using libraries to handle OAuth so far, but lately I've been digging deeper trying to understand the underlying OAuth process. Currently, I'm trying to connect to [Tumblr API v2](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) using OAuth 1.0a with this simple code:

```
import urllib, urllib2, time, random, hmac, base64, hashlib

def makenonce():
    random_number = ''.join( str( random.randint( 0, 9 ) ) for _ in range( 40 ) )
    m = hashlib.md5( str( time.time() ) + str( random_number ) )
    return m.hexdigest()

def encodeparams(s):
    return urllib.quote( str( s ), safe='~' )

# Actual key and secret from a test app created using a dummy Tumblr account
consumer_key = '97oAujQhSaQNv4XDXzCjdZlOxwNyhobmDwmueJBCHWsFFsW7Ly'
consumer_secret = '5q1dpF659SOgSUb0Eo52aAyoud8N8QOuJu6enCG92aDR6WoMlf'

#oauth URLs
request_tokenURL = 'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token'

#oauth params
oauth_parameters = {
            'oauth_consumer_key'     : consumer_key,
            'oauth_nonce'            : makenonce(),
            'oauth_timestamp'        : str(int(time.time())),
            'oauth_signature_method' : "HMAC-SHA1",
            'oauth_version'          : "1.0"
            }

normalized_parameters = encodeparams( '&'.join( ['%s=%s' % ( encodeparams( str( k ) ), encodeparams( str( oauth_parameters[k] ) ) ) for k in sorted( oauth_parameters )] ) )
# Since I'm focusing only on getting the request token for now, I set this to POST.
normalized_http_method = 'POST'
normalized_http_url = encodeparams( request_tokenURL )
signature_base_string = '&'.join( [normalized_http_method, normalized_http_url, normalized_parameters] )
oauth_key = consumer_secret + '&'
hashed = hmac.new( oauth_key, signature_base_string, hashlib.sha1 )
oauth_parameters['oauth_signature'] = base64.b64encode( hashed.digest() )
oauth_header = 'Authorization: OAuth realm="http://www.tumblr.com",' + 'oauth_nonce="' + oauth_parameters['oauth_nonce'] + '",' + 'oauth_timestamp="' + oauth_parameters['oauth_timestamp'] + '",' + 'oauth_consumer_key="' + oauth_parameters['oauth_consumer_key'] + '",' + 'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="' + oauth_parameters['oauth_signature'] +'"'

# sample oauth_header generated by the code above:
# Authorization: OAuth realm="http://www.tumblr.com",oauth_nonce="c200a0e06f30b84b851ac3e99a71054b",oauth_timestamp="1315231855",oauth_consumer_key="97oAujQhSaQNv4XDXzCjdZlOxwNyhobmDwmueJBCHWsFFsW7Ly",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="kVAlmwolCX0WJIvTF9MB2UV5rnU="


req = urllib2.Request( request_tokenURL )
req.add_header( 'Authorization', oauth_header )
# If all goes well, Tumblr should send me the oauth request token.
print urllib2.urlopen( req ).read()
```

Instead of the OAuth Request token, Tumblr returns **HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized**.

Things I've tried without any success:

1. Changed `oauth_version` from "1.0" to "1.0a", and changed it back again.
2. A guide on OAuth mandated adding the '&' at the end of `consumer_secret` to get the `oauth_key`. I tried removing the '&' later to see if that made any difference.
3. Checked if the OAuth parameters were sorted, and they were.
4. Did not add the string "Authorization: " to `oauth_header`, then added it back later. Neither made any difference.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You probably shouldn't have your secret key on here

Comment: @Cal It's a dummy app made specifically for this question. It's right there in the comments: `// Actual key and secret from a test app created using a **dummy** Tumblr account`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it after making just 2 simple changes in the above code:

1. **`normalized_http_method = 'GET'`** #not POST
2. **`oauth_header = 'OAuth realm="http://www...'`** # The word "Authorization" is unnecessary. I had taken this out earlier as listed in "Things I've tried without any success", but the error listed in (1) threw me off track. With (1) solved, I could see how "Authorization" was indeed unnecessary.

The OAuth Request token Tumblr sent me when I finally got it right:
**`oauth_token=mbRUgyDkPePfkEztiLELMqUl1kyNXEcaTCCwpb7SoXDF9mhiTF&oauth_token_secret=5pXllXGKA8orAaUat1G7ckIfMfYup8juMBAgEELUkeMZoC3pv6&oauth_callback_confirmed=true`**

↑

This is a one-time only token and I've listed it here just for the sake of completeness.