# iOS oAuth error while using Tumblr

Tags: iphone, ios, oauth, tumblr

I receive the following error when try to get the request token in Tumblr

**Url to get request token :** http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token

oauth_timestamp is too far away; we believe it is now 1318855109, you sent 1318900517, 45408 seconds away

Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309478/unable-to-get-oauth-request-token-while-working-with-the-tumblr-api-using-pyth

Answer (score 1):

The error pretty much tells your what's wrong: the timestamp you're sending is too far away from what Tumblr thinks is "now." Make sure you're using UTC rather than your local time and make sure the clock you're using is reasonably accurate.